# Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined - Youtube Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I created the following code to make videos play on hover:

```js
var player = [];
var el_number;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
 var players = $(".video");
 for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  el_number = $(players[i]).parent().parent().index();
  player[i] = new YT.Player(players[i], {
   events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady(i, el_number)
   }
  });
 }
}
function onPlayerReady(number, elnumber) {
 $(".article:eq("+elnumber+")").on({
  'mouseover': function() {
  player[number].playVideo();
  },
  'mouseout': function() {
  player[number].pauseVideo();
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<!-- Videos look like this: -->
<iframe class='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/(video_id)?controls=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&&enablejsapi=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It works perfectly fine, but after some time of loading scripts it shows me this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined          www-widgetapi.js:65 
    at K.g.I (www-widgetapi.js:65)
    at W.g.l (www-widgetapi.js:114)
    at W.g.J (www-widgetapi.js:127)
    at S.g (www-widgetapi.js:143)
    at k (www-widgetapi.js:95)
```

I ckecked Opera and Edge there is no error. After disabling every extention there is still that problem in Chrome. What is the root of the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's an issue with your callback definition :

```
onPlayerReady(i, el_number)
```

`onPlayerReady` takes the event data as parameter. To get the player, you can call `event.target` and store some data inside this object

For instance :

```js
var player = [];

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  var players = $(".video");
  for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    el_number = $(players[i]).parent().parent().index();
    player[i] = new YT.Player(players[i], {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
    player[i].el_number = el_number;
  }
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  console.log("event.target.el_number : " + event.target.el_number);
  $(".article:eq(" + event.target.el_number + ")").on({
    'mouseover': function() {
      event.target.playVideo();
    },
    'mouseout': function() {
      event.target.pauseVideo();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<!-- Videos look like this: -->
<iframe class='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/B_hLfhccYf0?controls=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&enablejsapi=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can find a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/0rwwaza5/2/)

Comment: In fact you don't even need to store the player index as you can get the player directly with `event.target`, see my updated post